# What does "recovering from crashes" have to do with windows.com?

Tags: windows-10, security, privacy

I read this today:

> Bitflips are events that cause individual bits stored in an electronic device to flip, turning a 0 to a 1 or vice versa. Cosmic radiation and fluctuations in power or temperature are the most common naturally occurring causes. Research from 2010 estimated that a computer with 4GB of commodity RAM has a 96 percent chance of experiencing a bitflip within three days. An independent researcher recently demonstrated how bitflips can come back to bite Windows users when their PCs reach out to Microsoft's windows.com domain. Windows devices do this regularly to perform actions like making sure the time shown in the computer clock is accurate, connecting to Microsoft's cloud-based services, **and recovering from crashes**.

Emphasis mine.

I understand the clock part, and the cloud one too (not that I would ever dream of using anything "cloud"), but "recovering from crashes" is puzzling to say the least. In my mind, I imagine that my entire RAM has been uploaded to windows.com and that it's re-fetched after the next boot or something. But that's too nightmarish to be true even in this dystopia, so it *must* mean something else.

But what is that "else"?

Comment: Where did you read this? Perhaps the best person the tell you what they mean is the person that wrote it.

Comment: @Mokubai [Bitflips when PCs try to reach windows.com: What could possibly go wrong? | Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/03/windows-com-bitsquatting-hack-can-wreak-unknown-havoc-on-pcs/)

Comment: Windows programs are known to phone home when they crash - looking for a solution to this problem or similar

Comment: **Microsoft is not uploading Gigabytes worth of memory dumps to themselves nor is it getting "fetched" from Microsoft.**  The amount of data required for NTP is insignificant.  The subdomains mentioned wouldn't have any significant amount of data either (i.e. windows.com/stopcode).  Like most articles on Arstechnica, the article in question  is poorly written, the author of the article never clarifies what they actually meant. The source material [did](https://remyhax.xyz/posts/bitsquatting-windows/) and it's harmless, and i have no doubt, Apple does something similar.

Comment: Basically any connection your PC makes to MS or really any other location, is subject to a low-probability condition where you might be connecting to the wrong server. bitflips could occur anywhere in memory, so basically any of the tasks related to connecting to another system could theoretically misinterpret what server you want to connect to. I wouldn't pay it any mind in particular; there is absolutely nothing you could do to prevent it, there is an infinitesimal chance that an occurrence magically happens to actually harm you, and its always been this way. its just a curiosity for now.

Comment: Why does nobody seem to understand what I asked about?

Comment: DavidPostill answered your question. Windows diagnostics will detect when many types of apps crash (Applications, not the whole OS), and ask you if you want to send information to Microsoft about the crash (depending on your diagnostic settings). . It might help them write an update to fix it. You can find more information about WER here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/windows-error-reporting the specific kinds of data reported are documented here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/wer-structures

Comment: @JahzeelX. Probably because without the context of the article describing the actual issue your suggestion that everything you do being uploaded to Microsoft is somewhat nonsensical and alarmist. It needs the broader context of the article to describe exactly what Microsoft might be doing and why it might be a problem. One or two poorly written paragraphs taken out of context is not a definitive description of a massive product such as Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It just means a description of the problem is uploaded and a solution is searched for in a database. The description is typically the name of the application or driver, the version, the particular error code, and a few other general details.